# Factors affecting .apk file size

Tags: android

This may sound like a silly question but I faced an anomaly while developing an Android application and I'd like to discuss it with more experienced and knowledgeable Android developers.

I'm developing an Android application. I have a private repo at place on which I push code as I make changes. The anomaly is, the Android Packaged File (apk) differs a little less than 50% in size on two different computers. On computer 1, the .apk file size is 1,037 KB and on computer 2, it is 541 KB. I use the same version of Eclipse on both computers and the exactly same code as I did on computer 1.
So,

- What the heck is going on here?
- Are there some secret factors that affect apk file size? If yes, what are they?

Your help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
As suggested by @CommonsWare, I extracted the contents of these two apk files via WinRar. I'm now listing the number of files and specific directory/file size in both apk's. Let's call the apk file with size 1,037 KB as Bigger_APK.apk and the apk file with size 541 KB as Smaller_APK.apk.

> Bigger_APK.apk

META-INF (directory). 3 files. Total size: 84.8 KB

res (directory). 413 files, 12 folders. Total size: 435 KB

AndroidManifest.xml (file). Total size: 2.61 KB

classes.dex (file). Total size: 1.48 MB

resources.arsc (file). Total size: 116 KB

> Smaller_APK.apk

META-INF (directory). 3 files. Total size: 16 KB

res* (directory). 82 files, 8 folders. Total size: 230 KB

AndroidManifest.xml (file). Total size: 2.61 KB

classes.dex (file). Total size: 851 KB

resources.arsc (file). Total size: 14 KB

Points to ponder after this comparison:

- Why is res directory file size differs when there are as many objects in the bigger file as there are in the smaller one?
- Why `classes.dex` file differs in size although I'm compiling the same code on same versioned IDE?

Comment: Look into the `/bin` folder in computer 1's project. I think you'll discover you left an old apk from a previous version.

Comment: "What the heck is going on here?" -- APK files are ZIP archives. Feel free to use a ZIP utility to see what is different, in terms of compression ratios, missing files, etc.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Did what you asked and didn't find what you thought I would. I went ahead, cleaned the project, built it, and exexuted it only to find out that .apk file size is what it was before: 1,037 KB

Comment: @CommonsWare Why would anything be different for the same project and IDE across two different workstations?

Comment: Perhaps they are not as "the same" as you think. That is why it is incumbent upon you to analyze the two APK files and be **much more specific** about what is different, besides the fact that the file size is different. For example, if you determine that the smaller APK file is missing its `assets/`, you might then look at the project on that machine to see if there is something unusual about `assets/` (e.g., they are from a Git submodule which wasn't initialized). Just saying "the file size is different" does not give us much to go on.

Comment: Sure. I will get to it and come back if I find more difference between these two .apk files.
But again, shouldn't the same code generate the same apk? Sorry if the questions seem a little too naive (or stupid to say bluntly), I'm just a newbie trying to find his way into the Android development world.

Comment: @CommonsWare Dug a litter deeper and extracted both apk's to analyze the files inside. I've updated my question accordingly. Please check.

Comment: The contents of res/ gets placed in your apk. This includes images and other resources. Diff the 2 res directories. These should be identical in your source control, and the fact that they aren't most likely explains the size difference.

Comment: But the number of files/directories are same in both apk's.

Comment: `Why is res directory file size differs when there are as many objects in the bigger file as there are in the smaller one?` **NO, they differ a lot:** `res (directory). 413 files, 12 folders. Total size: 435 KB` vs `res* (directory). 82 files, 8 folders. Total size: 230 KB` **413 files > 82 files**.

Answer (score 1):

Without much details, I'm going to play a guess game. So far I have come up with 2 possible answers:

1-) You are using proguard or some other obfuscator and the obfuscator configuration is different between computers. If you are using proguard, the config file is located in project.properties, usually pointing to `${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt`

2-) You are pointing to similar, but different dependencies.

Either way, I can only imagine the problem lies outside of your version control. Those 2 answers were the things I could think of. There should be more.

Comment: I'm not using proguard at the moment as the project is under development. 
Please elaborate "You are pointing to similar, but different dependencies."?

Comment: @BasitSaeed: "dependencies" means "code you did not write", such as Android library projects you got from third parties like Google (e.g., Android Support package). "similar but different" means pretty much what it says -- one machine has a newer version of the dependency than the other machine, and therefore they are contributing different contents to the app.

Comment: I understand. I do not have any third party dependency in my project as of yet.

Comment: Judging by the difference of number of files, I would say the smaller apk is not using unnecessary assets, either by a shrinking process, or simply because the folder is different. I recommend the use of proguard. It's simple to use, and you can get an even smaller apk from both computers.